# "What I'm looking for is/are [plural noun]"

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, be

Which one of these is correct, and if both are correct in certain contexts, which is preferred?

> - What I'm looking for *is methods* that help...
> - What I'm looking for *are the methods* that help...

I know this may seem a duplicate of previous questions like [Is it “5–6 weeks are a lot of time” or “5–6 weeks is a lot of time”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67553/is-it-5-6-weeks-are-a-lot-of-time-or-5-6-weeks-is-a-lot-of-time), but I think this is — not being about collective/mass nouns(?) — a somewhat different question.

(No, I'm not a native speaker of English.)

Comment: Using "is" is fine, commonplace English. Using "are the" is fine as well, so long as you know there are only a fixed, finite, number of methods, and you want *all* of them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [S-V agreement: It is not clear what is/are meant by A and B](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87681/s-v-agreement-it-is-not-clear-what-is-are-meant-by-a-and-b) (see especially  user21497's answer)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. So, is the first version (what...is) correct, because of the subject being "what" instead of "methods"? The Q&A you've linked seems to says so.

Comment: Both 'is' and 'are' may be used 'correctly' here; 'is' is the more common choice. Cerberus offers a possible reason for why the apparently illogical choice is favoured. With 'It's the Waltons', the 'it's' construction has become a fixed expression taking both plural and singular noun phrases. The same seems to have happened with 'What I want / need / like ... is ...', though here 'are' is also available.

Answer (score -2):

"are" is correct since "methods" is plural.  I can't envision a context in which "is methods" is correct, however "is a list of methods" is OK, because the list is singular.

Comment: Accepted usage is usually more complex than adherence to basic simple rules. For instance, 'It's us' is considered acceptable by most people, and better than 'It are us / It are we' by almost everyone. The linked previous question has answers going into reasonable depth.

Comment: Thanks, Edwin.  I agree.  I just didn't believe this case shared the complexity.

Comment: Oh, it does. It's a [_Wh_-Cleft (aka Pseudo-Cleft)](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+pseudo+cleft) sentence; the plural is optional and gets used only when emphasizing plurality. The normal verb inserted by the Pseudo-Cleft rule is _is_ (or _was_).